# Transformation of uniform distribution

Tags: self-study, distributions

Let $X$ have the uniform distribution $U(-1,3)$. Find the pdf of $Y = X^2$.

So $f(x) = \frac 1 4 $ for $-1 \leq x \leq 3$. I'm having some trouble figuring out how to do the integration in terms of what the bounds should be.

Comment: There is no integration to consider here but a direct application of the change of variable, once you separate between negative and positive values of $X$.